# Travic CI Commit fails (coverage_clover XML file is not readable)

Tags: travis-ci

So I manually changed a code in GitHub (something small). Somehow it fails even though my local test works.

This is the current test: [Job #44.1](https://travis-ci.org/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue/jobs/413980811#L596) and my last test worked fine [Job #40.1](https://travis-ci.org/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue/jobs/404832989).

What did I wrong?

Error-Code:

```
PHPUnit 7.0.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
unrecognized option --ansi
Script phpunit handling the phpunit event returned with error code 1
The command "composer run phpunit -- --coverage-clover ./tests/logs/clover.xml" exited with 1.
after_script
0.12s$ php vendor/bin/php-coveralls -v
In Configurator.php line 165:

  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  coverage_clover XML file is not readable                                       

Exception trace:
 PhpCoveralls\Bundle\CoverallsBundle\Config\Configurator->getGlobPaths() at /home/travis/build/pmochine/Laravel-Tongue/vendor/satooshi/php-coveralls/src/Bundle/CoverallsBundle/Config/Configurator.php:191
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  How did you do it?

Comment: @roundtheworld never, unfortunately! It somehow worked after weeks....